# Surface area of a sphere within a paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the surface area of the following:
1) the portion of the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16z $ that lies within the paraboloid $ z = x^2 + y^2 $

Attempt:so by  rearranging the eqn given we have a sphere with centre coordinates $ (0,0,8) $ and radius 8. Setting the eqns equal to each other ( the eqn of the paraboloid and sphere) I get $ z + (z-8)^2 = 64 $ which $ => z=15, z = 0$. I am sort of stuck from here. I tried saying that in spherical polars, $ z=r\cos\phi$ so by putting this into the eqn $ (z) + z^2 = 16z, $ I get $ r\cos\phi + r^2\cos^2\phi = 16r\cos\phi $ but this gives an undefined angle. What did I do wrong which led to an undefined angle - any hints on how to proceed with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the question is rotationally symmetric, so you are better off using cylindrical instead of spherical coordinates. Drawing a picture (by symmetry your picture can be just inside the $y$-$z$ plane) you see that the portion of the sphere inside the paraboloid is the portion where the $z$ coordinate is at least 15.

Comment: Does there not exist a part of the sphere enclosed within the paraboloid beyond z= 15? I drew the picture and it seems to be the case? Should we use cylindrical because there is symmetry with respect to one of the axes?

Comment: I meant to say there exists a portion of the sphere below z=15?

Comment: @CAF: if you solved the quadratic equation correctly, there shouldn't be a portion of the sphere below $z = 15$. The intersection points of the sphere and the paraboloid are the boundaries of those regions. The other region is bounded above by $z = 0$, and hence is a single point.

Comment: [Here is the graph](http://fooplot.com/plot/mrca8falo0). And yes, we use cylindrical symmetry because there is symmetry with respect to the $z$ axis.